# This for loop loops through the same values more then once?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Why does this for loop loop through the same Values more then once? I added the categories Class to the code so that you can see what I mean with that they are actual lists. These lists withholds values that are scrambled and that should be unscrambled depending on if they have the same three first numbers

```
     for(int i = 0; i < categories2.parentCategoryId.Count; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < categories2.NewCategoryId.Count; j++)
        {
            if(categories2.parentCategoryId[i].Substring(0, 3) == categories2.NewCategoryId[j].Substring(0, 3)){
                   
                Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryId[i] + " ");
                Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryName[i] + "´          ");
                Console.Write(categories2.NewCategoryId[j] + " ");
                Console.Write(categories2.NewCategoryName[j] + "\n"); 

            }
        }
     }




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrestaConverter
{
    public class Categories
    {
        public List<string> CategoryName = new List<string>();
        public List<string> CategoryId = new List<string>();

        public List<string> NewCategoryId = new List<string>();
        public List<string> NewCategoryName = new List<string>();

        public List<string> oldCategoryName = new List<string>();
        public List<string> oldCategoryId = new List<string>();
        
        public List<string> parentCategoryId = new List<string>();
        public List<string> parentCategoryName = new List<string>();

        public List<string> childCategoryID = new List<string>();
        public List<string> childCategoryName = new List<string>();

        public Categories()
        {
          

        } 
        public bool checkFirstNumbers(string categoryid,string correctNumber)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                if(categoryid.Substring(i) == correctNumber.Substring(i))
                {
                    return true; 
                }
            }
           
            
            
            return false; 

        }

    }
}
```

I have 3 categories in full which is 3 objects that withhold 6 different lists. Categories2 is a list of a bunch of subcategories that should exist beneath categories1. So these categories have two different identification ways either by id or name so we have NewCategoryId and NewCategoryName. These lists does not have two of the same values in them. But then we have the parencategoryName and parentCategoryId lists and these withholds the parentcategoryNames in the number of times that they need to show up to be able to place the subcategories beneath them. and now we need to compare NewCategoryID with parentCategoryId to see where to place NewCategoryName in our exceldocument.

Comment: *"this for loop"* - you mean *these for loops*. Have you tried stepping through in the debugger and examining the values?

Comment: yes the thing is that im trying to compare the two values as you can see but the loops compare them more then once

Comment: And what were the values of `i` and `j` each time?

Comment: if `categories2.parentCategoryId.Count` and `categories2.NewCategoryId.Count` are the same you would only need the outer loop and use the `i` variable on both of them.

Comment: Is there meant to be a `categories1` in there somewhere? Or... are you just bad at naming things

Comment: The values of i and j is 0 the first round for i and 0 for j and then j goes up to 117 and then i goes to 1 and it continues like that

Comment: "*The values of i and j is 0 the first round for i and 0 for j and then j goes up to 117 and then i goes to 2 and it continues like that*" - this is what happens when you nest *for loops*, the inner-loop iterates completely for ever iteration of the outer-loop

Comment: @JensSvensson yes, that is expected behavior. There are two loops, for each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop runs completely through

Comment: this is not my full code categories 1...2....3 is a object that withholds 6 different lists

Comment: YEs this is correct but how would you compare the two lists otherwise

Comment: What are you going to do?! can you explain a bit more.

Comment: i wanna compare all the values in both lists with eachother quz if they are the same i wanna write the two values in an excelarch next to eachother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain a bit, as mentioned in my comment, if both `categories2.parentCategoryId.Count` and `categories2.NewCategoryId.Count` are the same, your sample code could look like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < categories2.parentCategoryId.Count; i++)
 {
        if(categories2.parentCategoryId[i].Substring(0, 3) == categories2.NewCategoryId[i].Substring(0, 3)){

            Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryId[i] + " ");
            Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryName[i] + "´          ");
            Console.Write(categories2.NewCategoryId[i] + " ");
            Console.Write(categories2.NewCategoryName[i] + "\n"); 
    }
 }
```

Your code uses nested loops, which work like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // this is run 10 times
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
       // this runs 10 times for each iteration of i, so all in all 100 times
    }
}
```

If I understand your needed functionality correctly and you use `List<T>` You can use something like:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < categories2.parentCategoryId.Count; i++)
 {
     var match = categories2.NewCategoryId.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Substring(0, 3) == categories2.parentCategoryId[i].Substring(0, 3)));
    if(match != null)
    {
            Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryId[i] + " ");
            Console.Write(categories2.parentCategoryName[i] + "´          ");
            Console.Write(match  + " ");
            Console.Write(match  + "\n"); 
    }
 }
```

What should happen here is that the loop runs through the first list and in each iteration checks, if there exist an item with the same substring in the second list (`FirstOrDefault` either returns the first item that fits the result, or `null` if it doesn't find any). 
If a correct item is found, the same code as in OP is run.

Hope I didn't make any mistakes, doesn't have a code editor in front of me ;)

Comment: yes this is correct the thing is that my nested loops are there quz they are the same values in the lists but they are scrambled so they are not in order

Comment: In that case, iterate through one list and do a "contains" test on the other. It's still effectively a nested loop, but the test mechanism is different. You're trying to test not "sequence equality" but **"bag equality"**.

Comment: @JensSvensson ok, I think I understand now, will think about it a for a sec and update my answer. Are these Lists, Arrays or ObservableCollections?

Comment: and @madreflection How would you do that if you only wanna test the three first numbers

Comment: @JensSvensson and I my answer...does this answer your question?

Comment: Can you explain allittle bit more indepth? What your code is doing cuz i have not at all closely used FirstOrDefault in my life for ex

Comment: I think this will be correct though the last question would be how would i get what index in categories.NewCategoryId that the correct value is?

Comment: *"first three numbers"* - in the outer loop, iterate from 0 to 2 instead of 0 to `categories2.parentCategoryId.Count - 1`, I would imagine.

Comment: `ElementAtOrDefault` will return the value at a known index, not the index of a known value.

Comment: if i whant the value of both parentCategory and NewCategory that have the same id how would i go about that

Comment: For finding the index of an element you could try `IndexOf` method of the `List` type, about the last question, I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: quz i whant to get out where in the list it hits on both of the lists so what index it is that withholds the compared correct values on both of the values that i compare

Comment: So in the code above, if the code within the if statement is executed, you want to know the current index of `match` in `categories2.NewCategoryId`? For this you could try `categories2.NewCategoryId.IndexOf(match)`

Comment: i edited my question so that you can understand the full story

Comment: hmm, from your explanation, I would recommend looking into [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8). This would mean to refactor quite a bit, but I guess it would make things easier in the long run..